# minikube can't access remote Harbor registry

Tags: kubernetes, docker-registry, minikube, harbor

Even start minikube using `minikube start --insecure-registry "<HARBOR_HOST_IP>"`, when tried to run a deployment yaml file which include `image` path like `<HARBOR_HOST_IP>/app/server`, got error:

> Failed to pull image "[HARBOR_IP]/app/server": rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error response from daemon: {"message":"Get https://[HARBOR_IP]/v1/_ping: dial tcp [HARBOR_IP]:443: getsockopt: connection refused"}
>   Error syncing pod

How to set `insecure-registry` correctly in minikube?

---

## Edit

Tag current docker image with 80 port:

```
docker tag server <HARBOR_HOST_IP>:80/app/server
```

Push it to Harbor registry server:

```
docker push <HARBOR_HOST_IP>:80/app/server
```

Unfortunately remote Harbor host denied:

```
The push refers to a repository [<HARBOR_HOST_IP>:80/app/server]
00491a929c2e: Preparing
ec4cc3fab4be: Preparing
e7d3ac95d998: Preparing
8bb050c3d78d: Preparing
4aa9e88e4148: Preparing
978b58726b5e: Waiting
2b0fb280b60d: Waiting
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Even added `<HARBOR_HOST_IP>:80` to local `insecure-registries` list.

Answer (score 1):

It is working if you always define port 80 when you communicate with your docker registry which works on port 80.

Build an image:

```
docker build -t <REGISTRY_IP>:80/<name> <path>
```

Push it to registry:

```
docker push <REGISTRY_IP>:80/<name>
```

Start minikube with this insecure registry:

```
minikube start --insecure-registry <REGISTRY_IP>:80
```

Create deployment:

```
kubectl create -f test.yaml
```

where `test.yaml` is:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1                                                                                                                                                                          
kind: Deployment                                                                                                                                                                                        
metadata:                                                                                                                                                                                               
  name: test                                                                                                                                                                                     
spec:                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  template:                                                                                                                                                                                             
    metadata:                                                                                                                                                                                           
      labels:                                                                                                                                                                                           
        app: test                                                                                                                                                                                
    spec:                                                                                                                                                                                               
      containers:                                                                                                                                                                                       
      - image: 192.168.1.11:80/<name>                                                                                                                                                    
        name: test                                                                                                                                                                               
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. I have tried your way, and added the result to the question. By the way, why use `80` port? I think the default port is `80` and can use without `:80` in other container cluster. Is it the rule of `minikube`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you added secret in kubernetes?
Please refer the link to add secret: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>
```

Then use the secret in kubernetes yaml.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: <your-private-image>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
```